Pandas groupby and concat multiple rows
CONTEXT
I want to group by both a rule_id and calc_id and transform multiple columns into one row where each variable is concatenated with a ",'
DATA EXAMPLE
Calc_ID    Rule_ID    Name    Tracked?
100                   Rule1   Y
100                   Rule2   N
100                   Rule3   N
           YYY        Test1   Y
           YYY        Test2   Y
           YYY        Test3   N

EXPECTED OUTCOME
Calc_ID    Rule_ID    Name                   Tracked?
100                   Rule1, Rule2, Rule3    Y, N, N
           YYY        Test1, Test2, Test3    Y, Y, N

CURRENT CODE
I tried to apply a groupby one at a time for each of the columns but that doesn't work.
import pandas as pd

pd = read_csv(path)
pd = pd.fillna('') # <- to fix nans on groupby calc_id / rule_id

pd = pd.groupby(['Rule_ID', 'Calc_ID'])['Name'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
# pd = pd.groupby(['Rule_ID', 'Calc_ID'])['Tracked?'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
# ^ but this doesn't work because the initial groupby removes other columns


You should use agg to aggregate the values in each group, instead of apply:
df = df.groupby(["Calc_ID", "Rule_ID"], as_index=False).agg(", ".join)

  Calc_ID Rule_ID                 Name Tracked?
0     100          Rule1, Rule2, Rule3  Y, N, N
1             YYY  Test1, Test2, Test3  Y, Y, N

